# Print a number in decimal

Tags: low-level, number-formatting

Well, it is a low-level question
Suppose I store a number (of course computer store number in binary format)
How can I print it in decimal format. It is obvious in high-level program, just print it and the library does it for you.

But how about in a very low-level situation where I don't have this library.
I can just tell what 'character' to output. How to convert the number into decimal characters?

I hope you understand my question. Thank You.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far and explain how it has not worked for you, we aren't here to do your homework for you but we will help you reach the right answer.

Comment: What language are you using? Are we talking assembly here, or C, or something else? In C/C++, you can just use printf("%f\n"). You need to include something (stdio.h), but that's still pretty low level.

Comment: Also, floating point number representation is a pretty complicated topic. You can read all about it here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Yes, I know in high-level language, it is just a piece of cake
Just print it and it automatically output the decimal to you although it is stored in binary format...
Suppose I am writing in assembler and I can only output char but not number. How can I do it?

Comment: Ah, I see now that I was totally misunderstanding your question. I thought you wanted to print numbers that have a decimal point, like 3.14, not simply base 10 integers. The article I shared is useful and interesting, but not relevant to this discussion. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of printing decimals - on CPUs with division/remainder instructions (modern CPUs are like that) and on CPUs where division is relatively slow (8-bit CPUs of 20+ years ago).

The first method is simple: int-divide the number by ten, and store the sequence of remainders in an array. Once you divided the number all the way to zero, start printing remainders starting from the back, adding the ASCII code of zero (`'0'`) to each remainder.

The second method relies on the lookup table of powers of ten. You define an array of numbers like this:

```
int pow10 = {10000,1000,100,10,1}
```

Then you start with the largest power, and see if you can subtract it from the number at hand. If you can, keep subtracting it, and keep the count. Once you cannot subtract it without going negative, print the count plus the ASCII code of zero, and move on to the next smaller power of ten.

Comment: Thx! Maybe I am to silly, but why method 1 works? Actually, I learn a similar method to convert dec to hex (keep mod 16) in high school , but I do not ever understand why it works... Is this algorithm have name for me to google?

Comment: This method works because hex, decimal, and binary systems are [positional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation) (as opposed to, say, the roman system). The number is constructed as a sequence of consecutive remainders "glued" together in a single number. Each remainder is designed to fit in a single digit. Your program simply reverses that construction.

Comment: btw, your second method is great for me because I even don't have a mod

Comment: @Bear Yeah, it's a great method. I read about it some 25 years ago, when learning the assembly language for Apple][.

Comment: @Bear: `mod` is trivial to implement if you have `div`: `a mod b = a - (a div b) * b`. If you don't have `div`, subtract `b` from `a` until the result is less than `b`; what remains is the remainder, the number of subtractions is the division result. There are faster ways, but this is very simple to do.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want to tranform a number (stored in some arbitrary internal representation) into its decimal representation. You can do this with a few simple mathematical operations. Let's assume that we have a positive number, say `1234`.

1. `number mod 10` gives you a value between 0 and 9 (`4` in our example), which you can map to a character¹. This is the *rightmost* digit.
2. Divide by 10, discarding the remainder (an operation commonly called "integer division"):
    `1234` → `123`.
3. `number mod 10` now yields `3`, the *second-to-rightmost* digit.
4. continue until `number` is zero.

---

Footnotes:

¹ This can be done with a simple switch statement with 10 cases. Of course, if your character set has the characters 0..9 in consecutive order (like ASCII), `'0' + number` suffices.

Answer (score 1):

If integer, divide by ten, get both the result and the remainder. Repeat the process on the result until zero. The remainders will give you decimal digits from right to left. Add 48 for ASCII representation.

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt matter what the number system is, decimal, binary, octal.  Say I have the decimal value 123 on a decimal computer, I would still need to convert that value to three characters to display them.  Lets assume ASCII format.  By looking at an ASCII table we know the answer we are looking for, 0x31,0x32,0x33.

If you divide 123 by 10 using integer math you get 12.  Multiply 12*10 you get 120, the difference is 3, your least significant digit.  we go back to the 12 and divide that by 10, giving a 1.  1 times 10 is 10, 12-10 is 2 our next digit.  we take the 1 that is left over divide by 10 and get zero we know we are now done.  the digits we found in order are 3, 2, 1.  reverse the order 1, 2, 3.  Add or OR 0x30 to each to convert them from integers to ascii.

change that to use a variable instead of 123 and use any numbering system you like so long as it has enough digits to do this kind of work

You can go the other way too, divide by 100...000, whatever the largest decimal you can store or intend to find, and work your way down.  In this case the first non zero comes with a divide by 100 giving a 1.  save the 1.  1 times 100 = 100, 123-100 = 23.  now divide by 10, this gives a 2, save the 2, 2 times 10 is 20.  23 - 20 = 3.  when you get to divide by 1 you are done save that value as your ones digit.

here is another given a number of seconds to convert to say hours and minutes and seconds, you can divide by 60, save the result a, subtract the original number - (a*60) giving your remainder which is seconds, save that.  now take a and divide by 60, save that as b, this is your number of hours.  subtract a - (b*60) this is the remainder which is minutes save that.  done hours, minutes seconds.  you can then divide the hours by 24 to get days if you want and days and then that by 7 if you want weeks.

A comment about divide instructions was brought up.  Divides are very expensive and most processors do not have one.  Expensive in that the divide, in a single clock, costs you gates and power.   If you do the divide in many clocks you might as well just do a software divide and save the gates.  Same reason most processors dont have an fpu, gates and power. (gates mean larger chips, more expensive chips, lower yield, etc).  It is not a case of modern or old or 64 bit vs 8 bit or anything like that it is an engineering and business trade off.  the 8088/86 has a divide with a remainder for example (it also has a bcd add).  The gates/size if used might be better served than for a single instruction.  Multiply falls into that category, not as bad but can be.  If operand sizes are not done right you can make either instruction (family) not as useful to a programmer.  Which brings up another point, I cant find the link right now but a way to avoid divides but convert from a number to a string of decimal digits is that you can multiply by .1 using fixed point.  I also cant find the quote about real programmers not needing floating point related to keeping track of the decimal point yourself.   its the slide rule vs calculator thing.  I believe the link to the article on dividing by 10 using a multiply is somewhere on stack overflow.